# Parse NTEXT SQL Column into multiple columns for every word

Tags: sql-server, parsing, ntext

Hello I have a ntext column that contains a check image. In this check image there are a hundred or so words and values. What I am attempting to do is convert each word or value into a separate column.

```
    Check_Image Column
------------------------------------
this is an image of a check
===========================
address
data 
bla 
bla
bla 25% 
849324890234874
Discount -.088 
Subtotal 2.62
card
33934923 john smith
I agree to pay
X ___________________
thank you!


------------------------------------
```

I am attempting to split each word into a separate column to retrieve data within the check image of how much discount what applied to the card of John Smith.
Desired Output:

```
discount  subtotal     Bla 25%             card
--------  --------     ---------           ---------
-.088     2.62         849324890234874      33934923 John Smith
```

Thanks Guys

Comment: What is your desire output? Are those separated row or a single `NTEXT` with `CRLF`? Im not sure if you want a pivot or split or just the `0.088` value. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Apologies, I have added more descirpiton

Comment: The (n)text datatype has been deprecated for over a decade in favor of (n)varchar(max). You might consider converting your column.

Comment: Well aware unfortunately that is not possible at this time.

Comment: Your question is very vague. Are you wanting a separate column for every single word or each line? Is there any consistency you can count on? For example is line 7 ALWAYS the discount? There just is nowhere near enough detail to be able to even guess at an answer here.